# Warning: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php

Учу PHP все делаю по-учебнику, копирую код оттуда. Но у автора работает, а у меня вылазит эта ошибка! Где неверно? В интернете ничего толком не понял, как по мне все логично: 
создаем объект

```
$object1 = new User();
```

Обращаемся к свойству этого класса и присваиваем ему значение:

```
$object1->name = "John";
class User{ public $name;}
```

Но выпадает ошибка:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value

---

Вот полный код:

```
<?php
$obect1 = new User();
$object1->name = "John"; 
$object2 = $object1; 
$object2->name = "Phillip";
echo "Object 1 name - " . $object1->name . "    ";
echo "Object 2 name - " . $object2->name; 
class User { public $name; } 
?>
```

Comment: Предположу что проблема не в этих строках. Или в файле кроме этих строк ничего нет?

Comment: приведите полный код файла. Такое предупреждение выбрасывается при попытке обратиться к свойству объекта через переменную до того, как переменная была проинициализированна каким-либо объектом

Comment: Ну и стоит указать на какую именно строчку жалуется PHP (эта информация всегда есть в тексте предупреждения, однако вы посчитали ее несущественной)

Comment: <?php

$obect1 = new User();

$object1->name = "John";

echo "Object 1 name - " . $object1->name . "<br>";
echo "Object 2 name - " . $object2->name;
class User
{
 public $name;
}
?>

Comment: @RumusBin у вас при создании экземпляра имя `$obect1 = new User();` а потом `object1`. Очепятка...... а дальше у неизведанной переменной пытаетесь брать свойство.....а дальше тоже самое с `object2`

Comment: Да, обычная опечатка. Блин, как же трудно за всем уследить, всегда пыташься найти ответ по самому сложному пути, а оказывается всего лишь написание)))

Comment: @RumusBin но ведь есть же IDE с автокомплитом, где пишешь первую букву а он тебе варианты предлагает тех свойств и методов и просто переменных, которые у вас есть. Пользуйтесь ими..... а не какими-то блокнотами